# C++ SQLite Record not updating

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a `SQLite` database setup in my `C++` application as,

```
Database::Database()
{
    /* Create SQL statement */
    std::string sample = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SAMPLES("
        "FAVORITE       INT     NOT NULL,"
        "FILENAME       TEXT    NOT NULL,"
        "SAMPLEPACK     TEXT    NOT NULL,"
        "CHANNELS       INT     NOT NULL,"
        "LENGTH         INT     NOT NULL,"
        "SAMPLERATE     INT     NOT NULL,"
        "BITRATE        INT     NOT NULL,"
        "BITSPERSAMPLE  INT     NOT NULL,"
        "PATH           TEXT    NOT NULL,"
        "TYPE           TEXT    NOT NULL);";

    try
    {
        rc = sqlite3_open("Samples.db", &DB);
        rc = sqlite3_exec(DB, sample.c_str(), NULL, 0, &ErrorMessage);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            msgDialog = new wxMessageDialog(NULL, "Error! Cannot create table.", "Error", wxOK | wxICON_ERROR);
            msgDialog->ShowModal();
            sqlite3_free(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            wxLogDebug("Table created successfully.");
        }

        sqlite3_close(DB);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exception)
    {
        wxLogDebug(exception.what());
    }
}
```

and I have a function that inserts data into it,

```
void Database::InsertSample(int Favorite, std::string Filename,
                            std::string SamplePack, int Channels, int Length,
                            int SampleRate, int Bitrate, std::string Comment,
                            std::string Path, std::string Type)
{
    try
    {
        rc = sqlite3_open("Samples.db", &DB);

        std::string insert = "INSERT INTO SAMPLES (FAVORITE, FILENAME, SAMPLEPACK, CHANNELS, \
                              LENGTH, SAMPLERATE, BITRATE, BITSPERSAMPLE, PATH, TYPE) \
                              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, insert.c_str(), insert.size(), &stmt, NULL);

        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, Favorite);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, Filename.c_str(), Filename.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, SamplePack.c_str(), SamplePack.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, Channels);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 5, Length);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 6, SampleRate);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 7, Bitrate);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 8, Comment.c_str(), Comment.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 9, Path.c_str(), Path.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 10, Type.c_str(), Type.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);

        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            wxLogWarning("No data inserted.");
        }

        rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            msgDialog = new wxMessageDialog(NULL, "Error! Cannot insert data into table.", "Error", wxOK | wxICON_ERROR);
            msgDialog->ShowModal();
            sqlite3_free(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            wxLogInfo("Data inserted successfully. %s", ErrorMessage);
        }

        sqlite3_close(DB);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exception)
    {
        wxLogDebug(exception.what());
    }
}
```

and I'm calling it like this,

```
            db.InsertSample(0, Filename.ToStdString(), Artist.to8Bit(true),
                            Channels, Length, SampleRate, Bitrate,
                            Comment.to8Bit(true), Path.ToStdString(), "Sample");
```

the database is working fine, I have other deleting and removing functions for it. But today I added a column to it `TYPE` and inserted `"Sample"` to it, just to test, and have a update function like this,

```
void Database::UpdateSampleType(std::string& filename, std::string type)
{
    try
    {
        rc = sqlite3_open("Samples.db", &DB);

        std::string select = "UPDATE SAMPLES SET TYPE = ? WHERE FILENAME = ?;";

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, select.c_str(), select.size(), &stmt, NULL);

        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, type.c_str(), type.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, filename.c_str(), filename.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);

        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            wxLogDebug("Record found, updating..");
        }

        rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            msgDialog = new wxMessageDialog(NULL, "Error! Cannot update record.", "Error", wxOK | wxICON_ERROR);
            msgDialog->ShowModal();
            sqlite3_free(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            wxLogDebug("Updated record successfully.");
        }

        sqlite3_close(DB);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exception)
    {
        wxLogDebug(exception.what());
    }
}
```

I get the output as `Updated record successfully` but if I try to open the database in `sqlitebrowser` it is still showing as `Sample`.

Comment: You should add more error checks.

Comment: I added check for `if rc == SQLITE_BUSY`, `SQLITE_ABORT`, `SQLITE_NOMEM`, `SQLITE_LOCKED`, `SQLITE_IOERR`, `SQLITE_CORRUPT`, `SQLITE_READONLY`, `SQLITE_ERROR`, `SQLITE_PERM`, `SQLITE_INTERNAL`, and still only `Updated record successfully` prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I was passing the path as the argument, where I'm calling the `UpdateSampleType()` instead of filename. It's now working.